# Using jQuery $.when and $.then with two functions

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I know I can use `$.when().then()` if I have a `$.ajax` call in the `$.when` method. The thing is that I'm trying to use these methods while I call for another function in the `$.when` method and another function in the `$.then` method. The function I call in `$.when` method eventually calls a `$.ajax` method.

My problem is that it won't respond if I try doing it. I want it to do everything in the `$.when` method and then continue to the `$.then` method.

My initial function (called when clicking a button) is:

```
function HideForm(elem) {
    var valid = ValidateEmailPass(elem);
    var user, email;

    if (valid) {
        user_info_all.style.display = "none";
        ShowMessage(RegErrMsg, "נירשם, אנא המתן..");
        var email = document.getElementById('<%= reg_email.ClientID %>'), pass = document.getElementById('<%= reg_pass.ClientID %>'), age = document.getElementById('<%= reg_age.ClientID %>'),
        username = document.getElementById('<%= reg_user.ClientID %>');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Register.aspx/Register',
            data: '{user: "' + username.value + '", pass: "' + pass.value + '", age: "' + age.value + '", mail: "' + email.value + '"}',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (validated) {
                ShowMessage(RegErrMsg, validated.d);
                if (validated.d.indexOf('נרשמת בהצלחה') == -1) {
                    user_info_all.style.display = "block";
                }
            },
            failure: function (e) {
                $(reg_user_v).toggleClass('validated', false);
                $(reg_user_v).toggleClass('invalid', false);
                $(reg_pass_v).toggleClass('validated', false);
                $(reg_pass_v).toggleClass('invalid', false);
                $(reg_email_v).toggleClass('validated', false);
                $(reg_email_v).toggleClass('invalid', false);
                $(reg_age_v).toggleClass('validated', false);
                $(reg_age_v).toggleClass('invalid', false);
                ShowMessage(RegErrMsg, "אירעה שגיאה בעת ההרשמה, נסה שנית.");
                user_info_all.style.display = "block";
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

`ValidateEmailPass` function calls for multiple ajax requests, so I tried placing this function in `$.when` and the rest of the function in `$.then` like this:

```
function HideForm(elem) {
    var valid;
    $.when(function() { 
        valid = ValidateEmailPass(elem); 
    }).then(function() {
        // The rest of the function here
    });
}
```

Comment: Please show us your codes.

Comment: Let me post it, one minute.

Comment: @bipen I have posted the codes.

Answer (score 2):

$.when works on `promises`. In your case the `ValidateEmailPass` method should return deferred  and hence you must change logic as following

1. ValidateEmailPass must return $.Deferred instance.
2. Resolve/Reject the deferred instance inside ValidateEmailPass method once the validations are succeeded or failed. If you expect `then` part should not be called in case of validation failure, you should reject the deferred.

Quoting from jQuery.when [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

> If a single argument is passed to jQuery.when() and it is not a
>   Deferred or a Promise, it will be treated as a resolved Deferred and
>   any doneCallbacks attached will be executed immediately.